# Docker - understanding start/run

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I know I have images and instance of these images - containers. But.
Consider I have image image created for .net core app. Here is docker file.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/dotnetapp.dll"]
```

My `dotnetapp.dll` throws exception at startup.

So, now I can buld image:

```
docker build . -t my-image
```

Then create and run image:

```
docker run --name my-container -t my-image
```

Everything as expected - my dotnetapp.dll is run and then exception  is thrown (from inside app, as expected).

How I'd like to rerun (restart) my container. 
So I thought that `start` should be enough:

```
docker start my-container
```

But nothing happens (my dotnetapp.dll was not run). I have also tried to stop and start again:

```
docker stop my-container
docker start my-container
```

run also doesn't help:

```
docker run --name my-container -t my-image
```

because container already exists.

So, till now my pattern to re-run app is:

```
docker rm my-container --force
docker run --name my-container -t my-image
```

But I don't think it is proper way.

So why `start/stop` doesn't work in this case?  How to restart container so my `dotnetapp.dll` is run again without removing container?

Comment: hi, can you show log output? docker logs ContainerID

Comment: starting the container again does not automatically _attach_ to the container, so you won't see its output. I suspect the container is started again (and exited), but given that `docker start` doesn't re-attach, that wasn't visible. You should be able to see that it ran again by watching the container logs (`docker logs my-container`)

Comment: So, is it solved?

Comment: @thaJeztah Ok, so it is possible to start and attach at the same time? `docker logs` shows erros, indeed.

Comment: They're separate actions (`docker run` is basically a sequence of; `docker pull` (if needed), `docker create`, `docker start` and `docker attach`); to re-attach, it would be the same as doing `docker start`, then `docker attach`. However, attach will fail if the `docker start` failed before you attempt to attach